# Python unicode list join

Tags: python, string, list, unicode

I want to join a unicode python list, for example:

```
a = [u'00', u'0c', u'29', u'58', u'86', u'16']
```

I want a string that looks like this:

```
'00:0c:29:58:86:16'
```

How would I join this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
>>> a = [u'00', u'0c', u'29', u'58', u'86', u'16']
>>> u":".join(a)
u'00:0c:29:58:86:16'
>>> str(u":".join(a))
'00:0c:29:58:86:16'
```

Comment: Or the other way: `b':'.join(str(item) for item in a)`

Comment: I tried this and I keep getting a `UnicodeDecodeError` about unicode characters with an accent. Does anyone knows why?

Comment: @RafaelS.Calsaverini: If your error is on the `str` part of this solution it is because the character cannot be represented in ascii. If you need your unicode string in ascii you will have to make an approximation, try a solution like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8087466/267781

Answer (score -2):

How about this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        a = [u'00', u'0c', u'29', u'58', u'86', u'16']

        s = u''
        j = True

        for i in a:
                if j == True:
                        s += i
                        j = False
                else:
                        s += u':' + i

        print s
```

Comment: far too complicated - just use `join()`