# Approximately converting unicode string to ascii string in python

Tags: python, string, unicode, ascii

don't know wether this is trivial or not, but I'd need to convert an unicode string to ascii string, and I wouldn't like to have all those escape chars around. I mean, is it possible to have an "approximate" conversion to some quite similar ascii character?

For example: Gavin O’Connor gets converted to Gavin O\x92Connor, but I'd really like it to be just converted to Gavin O'Connor. Is this possible? Did anyone write some util to do it, or do I have to manually replace all chars?

Thank you very much!
Marco

Comment: see this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816285/where-is-pythons-best-ascii-for-this-unicode-database]

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not something desirable. You may endue having to add new replacements all the time. If would be really nice if you could explain why is this needed and why you must use ASCII instead of Unicode.

Comment: @sorin: Not if you use an utility that already has replacements for all Unicode characters.

Answer (score 39):

Use the [Unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) package to transliterate the string.

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode(u'Gavin O’Connor')
"Gavin O'Connor"
```

Comment: Just installed it.. but..
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode(u'Gavin O’Connor')
>>> "Gavin OConnor"

Comment: It means that `’` is a Unicode character, and there is no ASCII equivalent. `’` is not `'`, at least according to Python. You may want to make a dictionary of special characters like these and store a similar looking ASCII character. Then you can just replace the Unicode characters with the corresponding ASCII ones.

Answer (score 13):

```
import unicodedata

unicode_string = u"Gavin O’Connor"
print unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode_string).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

**Output:**

```
Gavin O'Connor
```

Here's the document that describes the normalization forms: http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/

Comment: That's just going to remove the apostrophe from the example input string. OP was looking for a way to replace it with the "close enough" ascii single quote character.

Comment: Hmm, on my machine it gives the above output, but when attempting the same thing elsewhere the apostrophe is just removed.. odd.

Comment: With my python 2.6.6, `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'Gavin O\u2019Connor') == u'Gavin O\u2019Connor'`, and `u'Gavin O\u2019Connor'.encode('ascii', 'ignore') == 'Gavin OConnor'`. I am beyond baffled by the standard you linked to, so I can't tell if that's a bug of `unicodedata.normalize`, or correct behaviour.

Comment: In 2.6.5 `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u"Gavin O’Connor").encode('ascii','ignore')` gives me `"Gavin O'Connor"`

Answer (score 9):

```
b = str(a.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

should work fine.

Comment: It doesn't work. It just removes all the non-ASCII characters when I try it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a technique to strip accents from characters, but other characters need to be directly replaced.  Check this article: http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-convert.htm

Answer (score -2):

Try simple character replacement

```
str1 = "“I am the greatest”, said Gavin O’Connor"
print(str1)
print(str1.replace("’", "'").replace("“","\"").replace("”","\""))
```

PS: add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of your `.py` file if you get [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639275/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file)

Comment: There are many other commonly used Unicode characters with similar-looking ASCII versions, like the various dashes and hyphens. It's too hard to do all that manually.