# Python "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file"

Tags: python

I am writing some python code and I am receiving the error message as in the title, from searching this has to do with the character set.

Here is the line that causes the error

```
hc = HealthCheck("instance_health", interval=15, target808="HTTP:8080/index.html")
```

I cannot figure out what character is not in the ANSI ASCII set? Furthermore searching "\xe2" does not give anymore information as to what character that appears as. Which character in that line is causing the issue?

I have also seen a few fixes for this issue but I am not sure which to use. Could someone clarify what the issue is (python doesn't interpret unicode unless told to do so?), and how I would clear it up properly?

EDIT:
Here are all the lines near the one that errors

```
def createLoadBalancer():
    conn = ELBConnection(creds.awsAccessKey, creds.awsSecretKey)
    hc = HealthCheck("instance_health", interval=15, target808="HTTP:8080/index.html")
    lb = conn.create_load_balancer('my_lb', ['us-east-1a', 'us-east-1b'],[(80, 8080, 'http'), (443, 8443, 'tcp')])
    lb.configure_health_check(hc)
    return lb
```

Comment: add # coding: utf-8 on top of the file.

Comment: There's no problem in what you posted; look in nearby lines.

Comment: Added an edit kindall, see anything in those lines?

Comment: Did you try Mutant's suggestion?  Do you have "smart quotes" (the curved and/or angled kind) anywhere in the file?

Comment: Yes Mutants worked, along with using notepad or something else to save the file as ASCII, then using it as you were.

Comment: One example which might cause it is an EN DASH (`–` - `\xe2\x80\x93`)

Comment: FWIW, I copied text from a Google doc into a comment string in my Python file. I carried over an apostrophe as in ```we're``` where the character ```'``` was the non-ascii problem. Hope my $0.02 helps someone down the road, also look for the various dash types and quote substitutions used in rich text documents. I was stumped for a few minute on this one.

Comment: Another way for linux/unix users could be to use the command `cat -v filename.py`  . This will show you non-ascii characters. These generally gets added when one copy code statements from some other editors like notepad, word etc.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You've got a stray byte floating around.  You can find it by running

```
with open("x.py") as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if "\xe2" in line:
            print i, repr(line)
```

where you should replace `"x.py"` by the name of your program.  You'll see the line number and the offending line(s).  For example, after inserting that byte arbitrarily, I got:

```
4 "\xe2        lb = conn.create_load_balancer('my_lb', ['us-east-1a', 'us-east-1b'],[(80, 8080, 'http'), (443, 8443, 'tcp')])\n"
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! Still not sure what the charter is/was. I ended up throwing the code in notepad and saving as ASCII, and then pasting.

Comment: I faced this as well, which I think was due to some copy paste issue, where the character showed up as whitespace in the editor(vim).

Comment: It might be needed to have python know that such characters are there for a reason and not just a stray byte. See the solution in Chris Redford's answer.

Comment: I had the same problem, character \xe2 was part of an hyphen "–" (\xe2\x80\x93), but slightly longer than the ascii "-". That's because I pasted text into vim, but didn't pay attention to this longer hyphen. For the full story, I produced this character with a double-hyphen "--" in a wiki text (using textile)

Comment: Mine was in an apostrophe - as in `O'Donnell`

Comment: Mine was a stylized double quote (“) as opposed to the simple double quote (").

Comment: yeah ... mine too was bloody pasting. But i was glad that npp has convert to "encoding" option. Saved me the trouble for searching for individual bytes. Tnx again :D you are a life saver! :D

Comment: Great fix. I had the exact same issue as @PlasmaBinturong, where I got the extended hypen from pasting into Vim.

Comment: For folks hunting down the problem character, [this table is useful](https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html). Everything in the "UTF-8 Bytes" column which starts with `%E2` is a candidate. Generally the issue is editing code with "smart" features turned on like "smart quotes" replacing `"` with `“` (U+201C) and `”` (U+201D) or turning `--` into `—` (U+2014 em dash). All of those start with "\xe2\x80" in UTF-8.

Answer (score 327):

If you are just trying to use UTF-8 characters or don't care if they are in your code, add this line to the top of your `.py` file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: for me it not working. below error showing always.                                                          SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /home/aslam/projects/deva_26nov/mylibrary/email_constants.py on line 393, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: Is there a reason this isn't a chosen answer?

Comment: @cph I wrote it 4 months after the question was asked :)

Comment: @cph because, while this is very helpful, the chosen answer answers the question of "what character is not in the ANSI ASCII set?" Both are fine answers though and the first one usually wins in that case.

Comment: This answer is works for me and I think its the right one.

Comment: In my case I had zero-width characters in my urls that I copied. https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php was a great tool to find them all.

Answer (score 43):

Or you could just simply use:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

at top of .py file

Answer (score 32):

\xe2 is the '-' character, it appears in some copy and paste it uses a different equal looking '-' that causes encoding errors.
Replace the '-'(from copy paste) with the correct '-' (from you keyboard button).

Comment: thanks a lot ! in my case it was the " ' " character

Comment: 0xE2 is not a hyphen in any common encoding. It is part of the UTF-8 encoding of many common characters like non-ASCII hyphens and quotes, though.

Answer (score 24):

Change the file character encoding,

put below line to top of your code always

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error while copying and pasting a comment from the web

For me it was a single quote (') in the word

I just erased it and re-typed it.

Comment: I had the same error, but while testing locally it didn't break and worked. But when ran on server it gave that encoding error. Had to replace the comments single quote to utf-8 version.

Answer (score 11):

Adding **# coding=utf-8** line in first line of your .py file will fix the problem.

Please read more about the problem and its fix on below link, in this article problem and its solution is beautifully described : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Answer (score 5):

I got this error for characters in my comments (from copying/pasting content from the web into my editor for note-taking purposes).

**To resolve in Text Wrangler:**

1. Highlight the text
2. Go the the Text menu
3. Select "Convert to ASCII"

Comment: Option has been changed to text->zap gremlins, in later versions of TextWrangler but it worked for me :-)

Answer (score 4):

Based on [PEP 0263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

```
Python will default to ASCII as standard encoding if no other
encoding hints are given.

To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must
be placed into the source files either as first or second
line in the file, such as:

      # coding=<encoding name>

or (using formats recognized by popular editors)

      #!/usr/bin/python
      # -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-

or

      #!/usr/bin/python
      # vim: set fileencoding=<encoding name> :
```

Comment: yet it worked from the first comment to the question, the answer contains the explanation. thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and just added this to the top of my file (in Python 3 I didn't have the problem but do in Python 2

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# coding: latin-1
```

Comment: This is going to be horribly wrong if your source is not *actually* Latin-1. You need to figure out the correct encoding, and then add that to the `coding:` spec.

Answer (score 3):

If it helps anybody, for me that happened because I was trying to run a Django implementation in python 3.4 with my python 2.7 command

Comment: Wasn't using Django, but this still helped me. I wrote the script using python 3 and tried running it with python 2. Error went away when I ran it with the right version. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I my case \xe2 was  a `’` which should be replaced by `'`.

In general I recommend to convert UTF-8 to ASCII using e.g. https://onlineasciitools.com/convert-utf8-to-ascii

However if you want to keep UTF-8 you can use

```
#-*- mode: python -*-
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 2):

After about a half hour of looking through stack overflow, It dawned on me that if the use of a single quote " ' " in a comment will through the error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file
```

After looking at the traceback i was able to locate the single quote used in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue running the simple .py code below:

```
import sys
print 'version is:', sys.version
```

DSM's code above provided the following:

1 'print \xe2\x80\x98version is\xe2\x80\x99, sys.version'

So the issue was that my text editor used SMART QUOTES, as John Y suggested. After changing the text editor settings and re-opening/saving the file, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to parse that weird windows apostraphe and after trying several things here is the code snippet that works.

```
def convert_freaking_apostrophe(self,string):

   try:
      issuer_rename = string.decode('windows-1252')
   except:
      issuer_rename = string.decode('latin-1')
   issuer_rename = issuer_rename.replace(u'’', u"'")
   issuer_rename = issuer_rename.encode('ascii','ignore')
   try:
      os.rename(directory+"/"+issuer,directory+"/"+issuer_rename)
      print "Successfully renamed "+issuer+" to "+issuer_rename
      return issuer_rename
   except:
      pass

#HANDLING FOR FUNKY APOSTRAPHE
if re.search(r"([\x90-\xff])", issuer):
   issuer = self.convert_freaking_apostrophe(issuer)
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this using pycharm. At the bottom of pycharm you can see file encoding. I noticed that it is UT-8. I changed it to US-ASCII
[image: pycharm encoding depiction]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it was because I copied and pasted the string as it is.
Later when I manually typed the string as it is the error vanished.

I had the error due to the `-` sign. When I replaced it with manually inputting a `-` the error was solved.

Copied string `10 + 3 * 5/(16 − 4)`

Manually typed string `10 + 3 * 5/(16 - 4)`

you can clearly see there is a bit of difference between both the **hyphens**.

I think it's because of the different formatting used by different OS or maybe just different software.

Comment: Probably you copy/pasted from some blog or similar whose software surreptitiously replaces hyphens and various quoting characters with "typographically pleasing" but incompatible glyphs.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem had caused due to "’" that symbol in the quotes. As i had copied the code from a pdf file it caused that error. I just replaced "’" by this "'".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spot what character caused this just assign the problematic variable to a string and print it in a iPython console.

In my case

```
In [1]: array = [[24.9, 50.5]​, [11.2, 51.0]]        # Raises an error

In [2]: string = "[[24.9, 50.5]​, [11.2, 51.0]]"     # Manually paste the above array here

In [3]: string
Out [3]: '[[24.9, 50.5]\xe2\x80\x8b, [11.2, 51.0]]' # Here they are!
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, the problem was caused by typing my code into Mac Notes and then copied it from Mac Notes and pasted into my vim session to create my file. This made my single quotes the curved type. to fix it I opened my file in vim and replaced all my curved single quotes with the straight kind, just by removing and retyping the same character. It was Mac Notes that made the same key stroke produce the curved single quote.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find what's the issue for long but later I realised that I had copied a line "UTC-12:00" from web and the hyphen/dash in this was causing the problem. I just wrote this "-" again and the problem got resolved.

So, sometimes the copy pasted lines also give errors. In such cases, just re-write the copy pasted code and it works. On re-writing, it would look like nothing got changed but the error will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of good solutions here.

One challenge not really addressed in any of them is how to visually identify certain hard-to-spot non-ASCII characters that resemble other plain ASCII ones. For example, en dashes can appear almost exactly like hyphens and curly quotes look a lot like straight quotes, depending on your text editor's font.

This one-liner, which should work on Mac or Linux, will strip characters not in the ASCII printable range and show you the differences side-by-side:

```
# assumes Bash shell; for Bourne shell (sh), rearrange as a pipe and
# give '-' as second argument to 'sdiff' instead
sdiff --suppress-common-lines script.py <(tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' <script.py)
```

The characters `\11`, `\12`, and `\15` are tab, newline, and carriage return, respectively, in octal; the remaining range is the visible ASCII characters. ([hat tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264915/remove-non-ascii-characters-in-a-file#comment52400979_3264944))

Another tip gleaned from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3208902/785213) uses an inverse character class consisting of anything *not* in the ASCII visible range, and highlights it:

```sh
grep --color '[^ -~]' script.py
```

This should also work fine with the macOS / BSD version of grep.

Answer (score -3):

When I have a similar issue when reading text files i use...

```
f = open('file','rt', errors='ignore')
```

Comment: This is terrible advice. You should figure out the correct encoding; discarding characters you don't recognize simply corrupts the data. The question asks about the encoding in Python source code, not in input text files, anyway.