# Python_Encoding_error message

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I was able to get the code working by following the below, but also changing a bunch of variable names seemed to work.  Perhaps I was using variables that were recognized by my encoder _UTF-8.  Thanks for the help

```
dt =0.1
a=100
n=int(a/dt)
kgrow=1; kshrink =0.25 
pgrow=kgrow*dt ; 
pshrink=kshrink*dt
length =[] 
l=0
times =[] t=0

for i in range(n):
t+=dt
times.append(t)
randgrow=random.random() 
randshrink=random.random()

length.append(l)

time=np.array(times)
lengths=np.array(length)

plt. plot (times,length)
plt. xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Length')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639275/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try to open it with notepad and save it as ANSI encoding.

[Save As.. ANSI Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h0Rb.png)

Comment: Hi Jorge Thanks.  However I cannot find ANSI encoding in my mac.  I see other kinds of encoding I can save it as, but not this one.  Do you have any suggestions?  Thank you for your help and quick response...

Comment: Sorry Joseph, i'm not a mac user :( i thought you using windows. Although you may try one of the many online tools like http://i-tools.org/charset

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably I had the most issues with encoding.. Here is "ALL" ways to fix it.

> First of all import this one to the your .py file.

import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

> After then open the cmd, right
>   click on the title, go preferences.

Choose "Lucida Console" for write type.

> Use "u" before your letters. Like x=input(u"Something: ")

There is tons of things I didnt write, first try them my friend.