# i have written the following program but i seem to get this error:

Tags: python, macos

the program is below,and the error i get is this

> File "python2.py", line 1 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in
>   file python2.py on line 1, but no encoding declared.

I am running python on macosx.

```
print "hello world"
print “Enter your name:”
nameEntered = raw_input()
print “Enter your Age:”
usrAge = raw_input()
nusrAge = int(usrAge)

if nusrAge <10:
    print “you are very young”
if nusrAge <20:
    print “you are a teen”
if nusrAge >70:
    print “you are pretty old”
if nusrAge == 13:
    print “you just began your teen years:”
print “Goodbye”
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639275/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file)

Answer (score 2):

Your text editor is putting curly quotes into your program.  You need to switch it to plain text.