# Regex for prices with euros pounds and dollars

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am using python regex to find all prices in a string. Thus far I am only having trouble managing the symbols correctly.
This code, with the input: `'happy$37.54000happy$34$3454$3333€27.80€3.00.33.2£27.000'`

```
   import sys
   import re
   price = sys.argv[1]
   new = re.findall(r'[\$\20AC\00A3]{1}\d+\.?\d{0,2}',price,re.UNICODE)
   for prices in new:
       print prices
```

ouputs:

```
$37.54
$34
$3454    
$3333
```

What I would like is:

```
$37.54
$34
$3454
$3333
€27.80
€3.00    
£27.00
```

If I add the euro sign into the code the file cannot compile given that it is not a unicode character. I was thinking that since `20AC` is the unicode for the euro symbol and `\00A3` is the unicode for the pound symbol that that would work, but it does not.

I believe that the issues lies in this part of the code:...

```
[\$\20AC\00A3]...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT FOR FUTURE PEOPLE - THIS IS THE BEST CODE ANSWER:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import re
price = sys.argv[1]
new = re.findall(r'[$€£]{1}\d+\.?\d{0,2}',price,re.UNICODE)
for prices in new:
    print prices
```

Comment: Somebody with more python-fu than me [can probably tell you](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1832893/505649) if something exposes the [Unicode character category Sc (Symbols/currency)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/index.htm) as a character class.

Comment: is it safe to assume that a period will always be followed by two digits?

Comment: What if you change `r'` to `ur'`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion kirby, sadly it did not work.

Comment: Thanks Jason, that's a good point, I have changed it to [\$\20AC\00A3]{1}\d+\.?\d{2}? (this does not solve the problem but I think is better code in the long run)

Comment: I have some small suggestions to your updated code.  You don't want `|` inside your `[ ]` brackets bc the square brackets already denote "any of these characters".  I don't think you need to escape the dollar sign inside the square brackets either bc it's understood to be a character in this context, but that may depend on implementation.  But my real suggestion is to group the period with the numbers behind it.  Your current version, given `$5.happy` would return `$5.`.  But if you group the period together and do something like `(\.\d{1,2})?` then it would return `$5` for that example.

Comment: I have made the first suggestion, but the second one (which uses grouping) results in the output looking like: .54    _    _    _   .80    .00    .00   .00    _  instead of $37.54    $34    $3454    $3333     �27.80    �3.00     �27.00    $2.00   $5.   This is kind of output seems to happen whenever I use groups in regex on python and I still don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `\u` for your unicode character codes in your regex. i.e

```
new = re.findall(ur'[\$\u20AC\u00A3]{1}\d+\.?\d{0,2}',string,re.UNICODE)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings

Comment: Thank you, this answers the symbol question. It is not perfect code as it ouputs:
$37.54
  000
  $34
  $3454  
$3333
  27.80 
  00.33
  27.00
,But it answers the question. Thank you

Comment: I fixed it. Now it matches the characters as well. You need to specify your regex in unicode format (with ``u`` prefix).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a regex that matches your examples.

`[$€£]\d+(\.\d{2})?`

It's worth noting that I'm making the assumption that a period will be followed by two numbers.  So this would match 3.50 but ignore 3.5.  If that behavior isn't desired, you want to adjust the regex to

`[$€£]\d+(\.\d{1,2})?`

which would pick up 3.5 in my example.

Comment: I have tried something similar, but I run into this error: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2'  .... Have you imported something that knows how to handle the €£ characters? Or did you use some flag beyond my re.UNICODE flag?

Comment: I don't have any experience with character encoding issues in python but maybe this answer will help?  

http://stackoverflow.com/a/24221963/3442448

Comment: That works! Thank you. (adding this at the top of the file: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- )

Comment: Nice!  Never underestimate the power of googling error messages. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can match with the symbols directly

[\$|€|£\20AC\00A3]{1}\d+.?\d{0,2}

[http://pythex.org](http://pythex.org/?regex=[%5C%24%7C%E2%82%AC%7C%C2%A3%5C20AC%5C00A3]%7B1%7D%5Cd%2B%5C.%3F%5Cd%7B0%2C2%7D&test_string=%2437.54000happy%2434%243454%243333%E2%82%AC27.80%E2%82%AC3.00.33.2%C2%A327.000&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: Oddly, my command line outputs: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' . But thank you for the feedback, this website will be helpful in the future. (I am sorry that I cannot upvote yet on this site)