# XML5617: Illegal XML character in IE9

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

My applications is working in IE11, Chrome but not in IE9. It gives XML5617: Illegal XML character error, but there is no illegal character, other wise it will not work in IE11 and Chrome. I am using Ajax to load the data. I am lost. Thanks for help.

Also it works in IE9 for english language customers but not for non-english.

Comment: Without being able to see the content that's causing the error, it's not likely anybody will know what's wrong.

Comment: May be related (ish): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639275/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file

Comment: please post you XML making troubles