# Encoding Issue-Python

Tags: python, youtube, soundcloud

I am writing a program to read a mysql table for a song and find the song on youtube. I want to download the song and put it up on my soundcloud account. I have tried to write code for that. The issue is that every time I run it, I get the following issue:

`Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file  on line 164, but no encoding declared`

Please help resolve the same.

```
import youtube_dl

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError

import sys
import pymysql
import urllib2
import urllib 
from urllib import urlopen
import json
import soundcloud
from goto import goto, label
import time


DEVELOPER_KEY = ""
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

global conn
conn=pymysql.connect(db='twitter_users', user='root' , host='127.0.0.1' , port=3307)
global cursor
cursor=conn.cursor()
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id= '',
                           client_secret= '',
                           username= '',
                           password= '' )
global song_name
global artist_final
global stored_title   
global genre 
def search_video(title):
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=title,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=10
  ).execute()

  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
        return search_result["id"]["videoId"], search_result["snippet"]["title"]


##youtube_dl configuration
class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        pass

    def warning(self, msg):
        pass

    def error(self, msg):
        print(msg)

def my_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'downloading':
        sys.stdout.write('\r\033[K')
        sys.stdout.write('\tDownloading... ETA: ' + str(d["eta"]) + " seconds")
        sys.stdout.flush()
    elif d['status'] == 'finished':
        sys.stdout.write('\r\033[K')
        sys.stdout.write('\tDownload complete\n\tConverting video to mp3')
        sys.stdout.flush()

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio',
    'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '0',
    }],
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
}


##main
label .start
if __name__ == "__main__":
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
    query=cursor.execute("select search_term from song_downloads where Soundcloud_TID='' order by id asc limit 1")
    if query>0:
        query_result=cursor.fetchone()
        term=query_result[0]
    else:
        goto .end    
    print("\tSearching video")
    try:
        videoID, videoTitle = search_video(term);
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            print("\tFound video: '" + videoTitle + "' - ID: " + videoID)
            Find=cursor.execute("select Youtube_VID from song_downloads where Youtube_VID=%s", (videoID))
            if find>0:
                goto .duplicate
            else:
                try:
                    song_name=videoTitle.split(' - ')[1]
                except:
                    song_name='Null'
                try:    
                    Artist_name=videoTitle.split(' - ')[0]       
                    if ' feat. ' in Artist_name:
                        artist_final=Artist_name.split(' feat. ')[0]
                    elif ' feat ' in Artist_name:
                        artist_final=Artist_name.split(' feat ')[0]
                    elif ' ft ' in Artist_name:
                        artist_final=Artist_name.split(' ft ')[0]
                    elif ' ft. ' in Artist_name:
                        artist_final=Artist_name.split(' ft. ')[0]
                    elif ' featuring ' in Artist_name:
                        artist_final=Artist_name.split(' featuring ')[0]
                    elif ' Starring ' in Artist_name:
                        artist_final=Artist_name.split(' Starring ')[0]
                    elif ' Feat ' in Artist_name:
                        artist_final=Artist_name.split(' Feat ')[0]
                    elif ' Feat. ' in Artist_name:
                        artist_final=Artist_name.split(' Feat.')[0]
                    elif ' Featuring ' in Artist_name:
                        artist_final=Artist_name.split(' Featuring ')[0]
                    elif ' Ft. ' in Artist_name:
                        artist_final=Artist_name.split(' Ft. ')[0]
                    elif ' starring ' in Artist_name:
                        artist_final=Artist_name.split(' starring ')[0]   
                    else:
                        artist_final=Artist_name
                except:
                    artist_final='Null'       
                if artist_final=='Null':
                    genre='Null'
                else:
                    try:     
                        api_beg='http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/profile?api_key=OZ8G9N2O7YFPZIRXN&'
                        api_end='&bucket=genre&format=json'
                        api_final=api_beg+'name='+artist_final+api_end
                        url= urlopen(api_final).read()
                        print('url read')
                        result=json.loads(url)
                        print('result decoded')
                        genre= result['response']['artist']['genres'][0]['name']
                    except:
                        genre='Null'
                if artist_final=='Null':
                    album_art='Null'             
                else:
                    try:       
                        api_image_beg='http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=OZ8G9N2O7YFPZIRXN&format=json&results=1&artist='
                        api_image_end='&bucket=id:7digital-US&bucket=tracks'
                        api_image_final=api_image_beg+artist_final+'&title='+song_name+api_image_end
                        url= urlopen(api_image_final).read()
                        result=json.loads(url)
                        album_art=result['response']['songs'][0]['tracks'][0]['release_image']
                        print(album_art)
                    except:
                        album_art='Null'            
                print(artist_final)
                print(genre)       
                ydl.download(['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoID])
                print("\tDone")
                stored_title=videoTitle + '.mp3'
                cursor.execute("update song_downloads set Song_Name=%s , Artist_Name=%s, Genre=%s, Album_art_url=%s, Youtube_VID=%s, video_title=%s where Search_Term=%s" , (song_name.encode('utf-8'), artist_final('utf-8'), genre.encode('utf-8'),album_art.encode(‘utf-8’),videoID.encode('utf-8'),stored_title.encode('utf-8'), term.encode('utf-8')))
                conn.commit()



track = client.post('/tracks', track={
    'title': song_name + '-' artist_final,
    'genre': genre,
    'artwork_data':album_art,
    'asset_data': open(stored_title, 'rb')
})

soundcloud_track_url=track.permalink_url
cursor.execute("update song_downloads set Soundcloud_TID=%s where Youtube_VID=%s" , (soundcloud_track_url.encode('utf-8'),videoID.encode('utf-8')))
conn.commit()
print("Track downloaded and posted to SC")
label .duplicate
cursor.execute("update song_downloads set Youtube_VID='duplicate' where Search_Term=%s " , (term))
label .end
print("sleep for 1 minute")
time.sleep(60)
goto .start


    except HttpError, e:
        print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639275/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file)

Comment: I am sorry I do not have the time to look in details at your code, but it is most likely a problem of unicode. You probably need to encode a unicode string somewhere, probably just by using `string.encode('utf8', 'replace')`. Have a look here: https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html.

Comment: Just so you know, I do see an error on the `cursor.execute` line where you just have `artist_final('utf-8')` which needs to be `artist_final.encode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used wrong quotes here:
Change Line 164

album_art.encode(**‘utf-8’**), --> album_art.encode(**'utf-8'**),

If you use an hex-editor you can search for char 0xe2 and substitute them with 0x27.