# VIM with youcomplete me

Tags: c, vim, neovim, youcompleteme

I've been coding for a while and moving from IDE to IDE is a real pain when what I need most is just ctag and code completion. I finally decided to go to vim, well neovim in this case but that's beside the point.

I have ctags working and was following [this tutorial from the YCM site](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#user-guide) along with [this one](http://www.alexeyshmalko.com/2014/youcompleteme-ultimate-autocomplete-plugin-for-vim/)

but I can't seem to get YCM to work for me.

I followed these step:

```
cd ~/.nvim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git
cd YouCompleteMe
git submodule update --init --recursive
./install.sh --clang-completer --system-libclang
```

this went through downloaded, compiled, installed some thing

Then I created the `.ycm_extra_conf.py file at "~/.nvim/.ycm_extra_conf.py"`

and added: let `g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = "~/.nvim/.ycm_extra_conf.py"`

to the top of my `~/.nvimrc file`

This is what I added to my .ycm_extra_conf.py file

```
# This file is NOT licensed under the GPLv3, which is the license for the rest
# of YouCompleteMe.
#
# Here's the license text for this file:
#
# This is free and unencumbered software released into the public domain.
#
# Anyone is free to copy, modify, publish, use, compile, sell, or
# distribute this software, either in source code form or as a compiled
# binary, for any purpose, commercial or non-commercial, and by any
# means.
#
# In jurisdictions that recognize copyright laws, the author or authors
# of this software dedicate any and all copyright interest in the
# software to the public domain. We make this dedication for the benefit
# of the public at large and to the detriment of our heirs and
# successors. We intend this dedication to be an overt act of
# relinquishment in perpetuity of all present and future rights to this
# software under copyright law.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
# EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
# MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
# IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR
# OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
# ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
# OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
#
# For more information, please refer to <http://unlicense.org/>

import os
import ycm_core

# These are the compilation flags that will be used in case there's no
# compilation database set (by default, one is not set).
# CHANGE THIS LIST OF FLAGS. YES, THIS IS THE DROID YOU HAVE BEEN LOOKING FOR.
flags = [
'-Wall',
'-Wextra',
'-Werror',
'-Wno-long-long',
'-Wno-variadic-macros',
'-fexceptions',
'-DNDEBUG',
'-ftrapv',
'-finstrument’-functions',
'-Wfloat’-equal',
'-Wundef',
'-Wshadow',
'-Wpointer-arith',
'-Wcast’-align',
'-Wstrict-prototypes',
'-Wstrict-overflow=5',
'-Wwrite-strings',
'-Waggregate-return',
'-Wcast-qual',
'-Wswitch-default',
'-Wswitch-enum',
'-Wconversion',
'-Wunreachable-code',
# You 100% do NOT need -DUSE_CLANG_COMPLETER in your flags; only the YCM
# source code needs it.

'-DUSE_CLANG_COMPLETER',

# THIS IS IMPORTANT! Without a "-std=<something>" flag, clang won't know which
# language to use when compiling headers. So it will guess. Badly. So C++
# headers will be compiled as C headers. You don\'t want that so ALWAYS specify
# a "-std=<something>".
# For a C project, you would set this to something like 'c99' instead of
# 'c99'.
'-std=c+99',
# ...and the same thing goes for the magic -x option which specifies the
# language that the files to be compiled are written in. This is mostly
# relevant for c headers.
'-x',
'c',
'-isystem',
'../BoostParts',
'-isystem',
# This path will only work on OS X, but extra paths that don't exist are not  harmful
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers',
'-isystem',
'../llvm/include',
'-isystem',
'../llvm/tools/clang/include',
'-I',
'.',
'-I',
'./ClangCompleter',
'-isystem',
'./tests/gmock/gtest',
'-isystem',
'./tests/gmock/gtest/include',
'-isystem',
'./tests/gmock',
'-isystem',
'./tests/gmock/include',
]


# Set this to the absolute path to the folder (NOT the file!) containing the
# compile_commands.json file to use that instead of 'flags'. See here for
# more details: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html
#
# You can get CMake to generate this file for you by adding:
#   set( CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS 1 )
# to your CMakeLists.txt file.
#
# Most projects will NOT need to set this to anything; you can just change the
# 'flags' list of compilation flags. Notice that YCM itself uses that approach.
compilation_database_folder = ''

if os.path.exists( compilation_database_folder ):
  database = ycm_core.CompilationDatabase( compilation_database_folder )
else:
  database = None

SOURCE_EXTENSIONS = [ '.cpp', '.cxx', '.cc', '.c', '.m', '.mm' ]

def DirectoryOfThisScript():
  return os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )


def MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, working_directory ):
  if not working_directory:
    return list( flags )
  new_flags = []
  make_next_absolute = False
  path_flags = [ '-isystem', '-I', '-iquote', '--sysroot=' ]
  for flag in flags:
    new_flag = flag

    if make_next_absolute:
      make_next_absolute = False
      if not flag.startswith( '/' ):
        new_flag = os.path.join( working_directory, flag )

    for path_flag in path_flags:
      if flag == path_flag:
        make_next_absolute = True
        break

      if flag.startswith( path_flag ):
        path = flag[ len( path_flag ): ]
        new_flag = path_flag + os.path.join( working_directory, path )
        break

    if new_flag:
      new_flags.append( new_flag )
  return new_flags


def IsHeaderFile( filename ):
  extension = os.path.splitext( filename )[ 1 ]
  return extension in [ '.h', '.hxx', '.hpp', '.hh' ]


def GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename ):
  # The compilation_commands.json file generated by CMake does not have entries
  # for header files. So we do our best by asking the db for flags for a
  # corresponding source file, if any. If one exists, the flags for that file
  # should be good enough.
  if IsHeaderFile( filename ):
    basename = os.path.splitext( filename )[ 0 ]
    for extension in SOURCE_EXTENSIONS:
      replacement_file = basename + extension
      if os.path.exists( replacement_file ):
        compilation_info = database.GetCompilationInfoForFile(
          replacement_file )
        if compilation_info.compiler_flags_:
          return compilation_info
    return None
  return database.GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )


def FlagsForFile( filename, **kwargs ):
  if database:
    # Bear in mind that compilation_info.compiler_flags_ does NOT return a
    # python list, but a "list-like" StringVec object
    compilation_info = GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )
    if not compilation_info:
      return None

    final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute(
      compilation_info.compiler_flags_,
      compilation_info.compiler_working_dir_ )

  else:
    relative_to = DirectoryOfThisScript()
    final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, relative_to )

  return {
    'flags': final_flags,
    'do_cache': True
  }
```

I have a project where I created ctags and I'm able to get around the file in vim using it's ctags support but, code completion just isn't working.

I went through the steps, went inside my ~/.nvim/bundle

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by typos in my .ycm_extras file

I run `:YcmDebugInfo`

and I get this error that my server has crashed:
Printing YouCompleteMe debug information...

```
-- Server crashed, no debug info from server
-- Server running at: http://127.0.0.1:64594
-- Server process ID: 47040
-- Server logfiles:
--   /var/folders/64/d3t4_pcs06943d651dfgp3m00000gn/T/ycm_temp/server_64594_stdout.log
--   /var/folders/64/d3t4_pcs06943d651dfgp3m00000gn/T/ycm_temp/server_64594_stderr.log
```

reading the stderr log I saw that I had some of these `"\xe2"` characters in my `.ycm_extra_conf.py` file.

Running a python script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639275/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file), I found the culprits.

I first changed to the proper directory where the .ycm_extra file was located then ran python:

```
Brother:.vim blubee$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open(".ycm_extra_conf.py") as fp:
...  for i, line in enumerate(fp):
...   if "\xe2" in line:
...    print i, repr(line)
... 
45 "'-finstrument\xe2\x80\x99-functions',\n"
46 "'-Wfloat\xe2\x80\x99-equal',\n"
50 "'-Wcast\xe2\x80\x99-align',\n"
```

removing the quote marks fixed the problem, now YCM works just as expected.

you can see the file before:

```
'-finstrument’-functions',
'-Wfloat’-equal',
'-Wundef',
'-Wshadow',
'-Wpointer-arith',
'-Wcast’-align',
```

and after:

```
'-finstrument-functions',  #removed quote after finstrument
'-Wfloat-equal',           #removed quote after Wfloat
'-Wundef',
'-Wshadow',
'-Wpointer-arith',
'-Wcast-align',            #removed quote after Wcast
```