# I'm getting"Invalid syntax" on an 'if' query

Tags: python, python-2.7

That is my code:

```
filename = raw_input('Filename? --> ')
‪if filename != 'q':‬
‪    my_socket.send(filename)‬
‪    data = my_socket.recv(1024)‬
```

when I run - I get this:

```
  File "temp.py", line 51
‪        if filename != 'q':‬
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried over and over to play with the tabs and spaced, but for nothing. It won't work.

Comment: It's not an indentation issue. Is there more code before the if statement?

Comment: Is this the complete code? You should check preceding lines as sometimes the error is due to lines before the reported error line

Comment: Are you mixing spaces and tabs? Is there some non-printing character at the start of your line?

Comment: Running your code give me the error describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639275/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file

Comment: you could run find out if the type of 'filename' is 'string' using 'type(filename)', if not, then the comparison operator '!=' will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains a number of unprintable unicode characters. This is why you are getting this error. I found the following characters(U+202A and U+202C) in your code using a non-printable character viewer.

I suggest you type in the code in a plain text editor again.

[image: Unprintable unicode characters]