# Add count objects in Django Rest Framework Viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a question with adding Count Objects in Django Rest Framework Viewset:
This is my curren API:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created": "2017-12-25T10:29:13.055000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "created": "2017-12-25T10:29:13.055000Z"
    }
]
```

Now I want to add Count Objects outside this API and collect them in **results** array like this:

```
{
    "count_objects": 2,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created": "2017-12-25T10:29:13.055000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created": "2017-12-25T10:29:13.055000Z"
        }
    ]
  }
```

How can I do this in the right way? Now my viewset.py is:

```
class NotificationAPIView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Notification.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset_list = Notification.objects.filter(to_user=self.request.user)
        return queryset_list
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

You again,you really should read [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) before ask.

Update:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from rest_framework.response import Response

class Pagination(PageNumberPagination):
    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        self.count_objects = queryset.filter(id__gt=2).count()
        return super(Pagination, self).paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view=view)

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count_objects', self.count_objects),
            ('count', self.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('results', data)
        ]))


class NotificationAPIView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Notification.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer
    pagination_class = Pagination
```

Comment: I know Pagination. But I want to add more object to count with conditions., Example, counts object with id >2

Comment: busy now,will update later.This should override get_paginated_response method

Comment: Okay, Thanks anyway :)

Comment: see update,it's untested code,if any error occur please tell me.

Comment: That's good. Success with this. But is there anyways better? Such as `annotate`?

Comment: annotate can add a field to queryset but can not return the field to front.If you want be simple,just override list method to custom response.

Comment: Got it, Thank you x3. Hope I have your half of knowledge :))

Comment: keep asking,one day you will  :)

Answer (score 1):

This will filter the values and add a count for the field `status` in the result.

```
def count:
    Model.objects.filter(value=value).values('status').annotate(count=Count('status'))
```

For detail [see documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You put it as separate function and call the function or in your existing `queryset_list = Notification.objects.filter(to_user=self.request.user).values('to_user').annotate(count=Count('to_user'))` since the to_user will be common in all the rows use that

Comment: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file views.py on line 20, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details` This error is created

Comment: I am not sure about the error may be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639275/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file

Answer (score 1):

`serializers.py`

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)

    count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_count')
    class Meta:
         model = YourModel
         fields = ['...., count']

    def get_count(self, obj):    
        return YourModel.objects.all().count()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate ?

Comment: it will add 'count' field in response and give the total number of data in that model