# Conda install: Packages missing in current channels

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I think something has gone wrong with my Conda. I am trying to install the package 'coding' and I get the following error: (but also other packages like tarfile I get a similar message like below).

Request:

```
conda install coding
```

Return:

```
    (../anaconda/envs/py2) :ud120-projects-master$ conda install coding
Fetching package metadata ...........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - coding

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

What should I do to fix it? Performing a 'conda install -c coding' does not help - like suggested on some other threads.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure what package you're trying to install... `coding` is not a package available from anaconda.org on any channel: https://anaconda.org/search?q=coding Are you trying to install this: https://pypi.org/project/coding/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. 

Originally I thought i need the coding input, because of another error I was getting:

line 29
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file .

Comment: Does this question fix your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/q/21639275/2449192

Comment: I tried it before and it did not work, but now i put '# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
' at the beginning of the .py file and it worked!!! Thank you so much.

Quick question still. What did this actually do?

Comment: This changed the Python interpreter to read the text as utf-8 rather than ASCII. I'm not sure of the details though.

Answer (score 4):

Try doing `anaconda search -t conda coding`. Check for the exact package you are looking for and whether it is supported for your platform. If you get the package you are looking for, get the package details by doing `anaconda show <FULL_PACKAGE_NAME>`. This command will give you the exact command with the channel, from where you can install the package.