# How do you identify the unicode value for a character?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to replace this value from my text file `•`

Google says it is u"\u2022", but when I do this nothing prints

```
from unidecode import unidecode

text = open('file.txt','r+')

l=[]

for i in text.readlines():
    if  unidecode(u"\u2022") in i:
        print "confirmed %r" % i
```

It prints out the lines if I go into the file and replace the values with an asterisk.

I tried putting the character into its own file

```
from unidecode import unidecode

import unicodedata

text = open('unicode_char.txt','r+')

for i in text:
    print unidecode(i)
```

That serves UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Edit -

I figured it out.

```
point = unichr(8226)
encoded = point.encode('utf-8')

for i in text.readlines():
     if encoded in i:
         print i
```

Comment: Why are you using `unidecode`?

Comment: I've added the [tag:python-2.x] tag because judging by your syntax, it seems that you're using Python 2. The way strings with non-ASCII characters are handled is different between Python 2 and 3, so the answer could easily depend on that.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to compare the unicode value to the values in i. Good call @DavidZ

Comment: Just use Python3 and do `if "•" in i:`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a specific character, you could try just copying and pasting it directly into the code, ie,

```
if 'ߦ' in i:
...
```

but some of those can be a pain to get, so try this:

```
if chr(2022) in i:
...
```

Sorry if I misunderstood the question

Comment: That serves SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file script4.py on line 9, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: I don't know the character number, so I can't do chr(2022).

Comment: I think the '\xe2' is causing a bunch of problems, in both the in built unicode decoder and imported one. Look here to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639275/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file