# Python Selenium find_elements_by_class_name Error

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping a google page that has returned links to Linkedin profiles.

I want to collect the links on a page and put them in a python list.

Problem is I can't seem to properly extract them from the page and I don't know why.

Google source code looks like this:

The page displays 10 of the following:

```
Mary Smith - Director of Talent Acquisition ...
https://www.linkedin.com › marysmith
Anytown, Arizona 500+ connections ... Experienced Talent Acquisition Director, with a 
demonstrated history of working in the marketing and advertising ...
```

The source code looks like this:

```
<div data-hveid="CAIQAA" data-ved="2ahUKEwjLv6HMr4HmAhWluVkKHfjfA1EQFSgAMAF6BAgCEAA">
   <div class="rc"> 
       <div class="r">
           <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/marysmith" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://www.linkedin.com/in/marysmith&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjLv6HMr4HmAhWluVkKHfjfA1EQFjABegQIAhAB">
               <h3 class="LC20lb"><span class="S3Uucc">Mary Smith - Director of Talent Acquisition, Culture Curator ...</span></h3><br>
               <div class="TbwUpd">
                   <cite class="iUh30 bc">https://www.linkedin.com › marysmith</cite>
              </div>
           </a>
           ...
```

In my script I'm using Selenium and `find_element_by_class_name()`to collect all the instances of the links to Linkedin.  The one in the above example is `https://www.linkedin.com › marysmith`.  It is one line of code where I use `driver.find_element_by_class_name()` with the particular class name:

```
linkedin_urls = driver.find_element_by_class_name("iUh30 bc")
```

However I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="iUh30 bc"]"}
```

I've tried various permutations and other classes but it won't work.  If I use the X_Path for one of those links the script WILL return that single link.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried "iUh30" or "bc" individually?

Comment: Tried both separately.  Neither worked.

Comment: I also tried "iUh30.bc" and it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Websites like Google and Facebook use an AI to construct the pages
sources and assign random classes that's why you are getting no such
element because every time you load that page the class's value varies
To solve this issue try to use constant tags or attributes.

Try something like:

```
#<cite class="iUh30 bc">https://www.linkedin.com › mary-smith-mckenzie-8b660799</cite>
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//cite[contains(text(),'›') and contains(text(),'linkedin.com')]")
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try your solution `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file C:/Users//Documents/Python Scripts/jobscrape/jobscrape.py on line 39, but no encoding declared;`  Thoughts?

Comment: @Windstorm1981 have a look at this [Python “SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639275/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file)

Answer (score 0):

That method is known to be buggy.
Try:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".iUh30.bc")
```

Comment: linkedin_urls still comes up empty and non-iterable.  Thoughts?

Comment: find_element methods return 1 element, find_elements methods return a list