# "ASCII-ish" approximation of some Unicode characters in Python

Tags: python, text, unicode, ascii

For reasons I don't control, I have to convert (English) text with some Unicode characters to ASCII (for further processing elsewhere). For example:

```
Deutsche Börse
```

When I do:

```
u'Deutsche Börse'.encode(encoding='ascii', errors='replace')
```

I get

```
b'Deutsche B?rse'
```

Which is not exactly what I need. Ideally I would like to get `Deutsche Borse`.

I realize of course that vast majority of Unicode characters that's not possible. But for many important names, like say `Quebec`, that's possible in principle.

How can I do that?

Comment: a German would say that it should be converted to "Deutsche Boerse". If you just need to remove the diacritics then it's a duplicate of [What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/517923/995714)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I just googled it and found a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087381/approximately-converting-unicode-string-to-ascii-string-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need :
For converting to ASCII you might want to try unicodedata

```
import unicodedata

data= u'Deutsche Börse'

print (unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', data).encode('ascii','ignore'))
```

**Output**

```
 b'Deutsche Borse'
```

Comment: A good answer, but, unfortunately, due to working on an answer in parallel unbeknownst to each other, an effective duplicate of Rakesh's (who happened to press `Post Your Answer` a mere minute or so earlier).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `unicodedata` module.

**Ex:**

```
import unicodedata
s = u'Deutsche Börse'
print unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

**Output:**

```
Deutsche Borse
```